# Doubt related to splitting of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> > Proper Splitting: Let $A $ be matrix of order $m \times n$ such that $A=M-N$ is called proper splitting of $A$ if $col(A)=col(M)$ and $null(A)=null(M).$

I need to observe some property of this matrix $A$?

a) If $A$ has proper splitting then $ R(N) \subseteq R(M)$

Proof:   Let $x \in R(N)$ then $Ny=x$ for some $y$

$(M-A)y=x \implies My-Mz=x$ since $R(A)=R(M)$
$$= M(y-z)=x \implies Mz_1=x \implies x \in R(M).$$

Hence the result is proved.

Is my proof is correct?

Please give some reference books/articals to read about this type of splitting of matrix.

b) In general, If two matrices are in row equivalent form then they row spaces are same but column space need not be same and viceversa is also true.

But In this splitting $col(A)=col(M)$ $null(A)=null(M)$ does this implies that $col(A^T)=col(M^T)$ ( that is the row space of $A$ and $M$ are same)?

Comment: Your proof is correct. More rapidly:
$$R(N)=R(M-A)\subseteq R(M)-R(A)=R(M)-R(M)=R(M).$$
Similarly,
$$\ker N=\ker(M-A)\supseteq\ker M\cap\ker A=\ker M.$$

Comment: from $R(M)=R(A) \implies R(M^T)=R(A^T)??$

Comment: I don't understand this comment. I never used that (wrong) implication.

Comment: I have edit my questions please check it once.

Comment: So now you added a second question. Please focus on one question per post, show your efforts to solve it, and explain where you are stuck. As for that second question: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1958485).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the comment, Also can you suggest some reference book for these kind of subspaces inequality.